# Android Studio - HorizontalScollView not moving

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I am doing some Android Studio courses. As part of this I am working on a mock-up music player app. The app should be mostly XML as not functionality needs to be added.
I am trying to build e Discover (new music) screen, where you have media like views. To do this, I want to implement an HorizontalScrollView. 
The problem is that my scroll view doesn't move. The xml code looks fine to me and I also googled this but did not find anything that would help my situation.

Would very much appreciate some clarification on this. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.alexcojocaru.vibes.Discover">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="Recommendations"
            android:textColor="#cc3300" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:src="@drawable/bear" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="My Name is Bear"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Nahko"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="13px">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:padding="6px"
                        android:src="@drawable/omam" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Beneath The Skin"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Of Monsters and Men"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="13px">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:padding="6px"
                        android:src="@drawable/jmj" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Essential Recollection"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Jean-Michel Jarre"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="13px">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:padding="6px"
                        android:src="@drawable/ram" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Random Access Memories"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Daft Punk"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the code is working fine

Comment: Cool, thanks! My problem was that I was viewing it in preview mode, where HorizontalScrollView doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the above code and it works by default.
I think the problem is that if the layout fits fully on screen then you might not be able to see the scroll.
Suggesting to test on a smaller screen.

P.S:Not enough rep for comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem is that if I try to run the app on an emulated device, the app keeps crashing with this error: "Vibes has stopped" or "System UI is not working". I also can't run it on a physical device as I only have an iPhone... (I need to get a test device soon)...

Comment: Also Please note vertical scroll works in preview mode but horizontal scroll doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please change HorizontalScrollView as follows

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="5px"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">
```

Comment: Did this but it doesn't seem to change anything... I think the problem is that I am looking at in preview mode as the emulated device keeps crashing...

Comment: firstly resolve all bugs and run it and check you will not get desired output. remove android:fillViewport="true" it is not necessary

Comment: Remove your ConstraintLayout with RelativeLayout it will work. Have you made adjustment for ConstraintLayout ??